# Dump Postgres 9.3 data with indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, pg-dump

When using

```
pg_dump --section post-data
```

I get a dump that contains the *definitions* of the indexes but not the index data. As the database I'm working on is really big and complex, recreating the indexes takes a lot of time.

Is there a way get the index data into my dump, so that I can restore an actually working database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to include index data in a logical dump (`pg_dump`).

There's no way to extract index data from the SQL level, where `pg_dump` operates, nor any way to write it back. Indexes refer to the physical structure of the table (tuple IDs by page and offset) in a way that isn't preserved across a dump and reload anyway.

You can use a low-level disk copy using `pg_basebackup` if you want to copy the whole DB, indexes and all. Unlike a `pg_dump` you can't restore this to a different PostgreSQL version, you can't dump just one database, etc; it's all or nothing.